# Scala. How to Unmarshall Option values using json spray?

Tags: json, scala, unmarshalling, spray-json, scala-option

I'm using json-spray library to unmarshall a json array.
Here is the code.

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport._
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._

 def unmarshalProfiles(response: HttpResponse): Future[Array[Profile]] = {
        implicit val profileFormat = jsonFormat16(Profile)
        println("[RES - SUCCESS] Request returned with " + response.status)
        return  Unmarshal(response.entity).to[Array[Profile]]
      }
```

The remote server writes its response as a json array. No problems if the response is fullfilled with one or more items. However, if no Profile item is available, the server returns ***null*** (not an empty array) and while unmarshalling I get the error ***'Expected Array as JsArray, but got null'***.

I thought that a good option would be to wrap the Array[Profile] into a Option object.
So I changed the code into the following.

```
 def unmarshalProfiles(response: HttpResponse): Future[Option[Array[Profile]]] = {
        implicit val profileFormat = jsonFormat16(Profile)
        println("[RES - SUCCESS] Request returned with " + response.status)
        return  Unmarshal(response.entity).to[Option[Array[Profile]]]
      }
```

Still, when the response is a null object, I'm obtaining the same error.
Does exist a way to unmarshall a Option object when it is ***None***?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the option to work all along with options. That means, to define your method like that:

```
def unmarshalProfiles(response: HttpResponse)(implicit mat: Materializer): Future[Option[Array[Profile]]] = {
  implicit val profileFormat = jsonFormat16(Profile)
  Unmarshal(Option(response.entity)).to[Option[Array[Profile]]]
}
```

Then `null` will be marshalled into `None`, and an existing array will become `Some(...)`